# Generate Sitemap with SharePoint online 2013 on Office 365

Tags: portalsitemapprovider

I need to generate a sitemap with all the links available in my site collection with SharePoint 2013 which is hosted on Office 365. Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Comment: An XML sitemap or a sitemap page?

Comment: Sitemap page where I can see all the links available in the entire SharePoint website.

Comment: Are you looking for an out of the box solution or is code deployment an option?

Comment: Please let me know about the both ways.